# metric learning in python

Tags: python, distance, similarities, metric

What is the common way to do metric learning using python? I'm already familiar with the [`metric-learn`](https://github.com/all-umass/metric-learn) package, is there any other packages? It does not contain all of the algorithms I saw [here](http://researchers.lille.inria.fr/abellet/talks/metric_learning_tutorial_CIL.pdf).  Perhaps I should use another language?

Comment: Anyone? Is my question not good?

Answer (score 0):

metric-learn is the most comprehensive package so far for Python. If it does not have the algorithm you need, you will need to search for a specific package with a Python implementation. Typically on Google/PyPi/Github.

If nothing is found, you may have to implement it yourself. If a C/C++ implementation is available you can make that accessible to Python using pybind11 or similar.